# page visitors go after they land on UTM campaign page - GA

Tags: google-analytics, utm

I'm trying to isolate Google Analytics traffic coming from a campaign (via a UTM) and determine the page visitors go after they land on the campaign page. I know I can do this by using Page and Previous Page path, and applying a segment, but I was wondering if there is a another way? Thanks./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use User Explorer report to see any single Google Analytics user navigation.

Anyway you can also use a custom report with source / medium, landing page and page but if you want to see these chronologically you have to pass some additional information in custom dimensions such as timestamp, then add these as dimension in the report.